# Conditional Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Choose a random integer $X$ from the interval
$[0, 4]$. Then choose a random integer $Y$ from the interval
$[0, x]$, where $x$ is the observed value of $X$. Make assumptions
about the marginal pmf $f_X(x)$ and the conditional
pmf $h(y | x)$ and compute $P(X + Y > 4)$.

---

I tried to make a sample space of the ordered pairs and came up with:

$S=$ { $(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(4,0),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4)$ }

(a total of 15 ordered pairs)

Next, I defined the pmf $f_X(x)$ as:

$f_X(x) =$
$\frac{1}{15} , x=0;\frac{2}{15} , x=1;\frac{3}{15} , x=2;\frac{4}{15} , x=3;\frac{5}{15} , x=4;$

(sorry for the messy piecewise display)

My idea ended up being wrong. Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: How about X is uniform on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and Y |x is uniform on $\{1,..x\}$?

Comment: The only info I am given is in the question itself. Not sure on uniformity.

Comment: "Random" is often used informally (and wrongly) to imply in addition uniform distribution. The author of the problem presumably knows better.

Answer (score 1):

If $X=3$, then we get sum $\gt 4$ with probability $\frac{2}{4}$, and if $X=4$ we get sum $\gt 4$ with probability $\frac{4}{5}$, so the required probability is $\frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{2}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{4}{5}$.

Comment: can you explain more, I am not quite sure what you mean. How are you adding $X$ and getting a probability?

Comment: If the first pick is $\le 4$, there is no way we will get a sum greater than $4$. If $X=3$, then we get a sum $\gt 4$ precisely if $Y=2$ or $Y=3$. So the conditional probability that the sum is $\gt 4$ given $X=3$ is $\frac{2}{4}$. This is because the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=3$ is uniform on $[0,3]$.

Comment: The first pick can't be $\le 4$ ? Isn't $X=3$ your first pick? And the choices for $x$ are $0,1,2,3,4$? (5 choices), and only two are valid to satisfy $P(X+Y>4)$? I am not seeing where the $\frac{2}{4}$ is coming from.

Comment: Also, may you comment on the work I provided. Just let me know if I am on right track or totally wrong.

Comment: The sample space is OK, note not all equally likely. The probability mass function is certainly not that of $X$.